# Why undefined var is not added to window object JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, scope, global-variables, undefined, window-object

As far as I know the following declaration will not add any value to the variable `aa`:

```
var aa = undefined;

function a () {
    var aa;
    console.log(aa);  // here aa is still undefined
    if(!aa) {
        aa = 11;  // should add to the globle scope (window Object)
        bb = 12;  // should add to the globle scope (window Object)
    }
    console.log(aa);
    console.log(aa);  // should be 11
    console.log(bb);  // should be 12
}
```

Now if I want to use access the vars `aa` and `bb`, I can get access only `bb` not `aa`.
My question is why `aa` cannot be accessed from outside, because in the declaration I haven't assigned any value to it and it is still undefined?

Thank you.

Comment: you have redefined aa to be in the function scope, and since you didn't assign a value, it has assigned undefined

Comment: You are redeclaring the variable aa in your function

Comment: @JonathandeM.: So do you mean `undefined` is the value that is being assigned to the variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at my comments

```
var aa = undefined; // global scope

function a () {
    if(true) { // useless
        var aa; // declare aa in the function scope and assign undefined
        // to work on the global aa you would remove the above line
        console.log(aa);  // here aa is still undefined
        if(!aa) {
            aa = 11;  // reassign the local aa to 11
            bb = 12;  // assign 12 to the global var bb
        }
        console.log(aa); // aa is 11
    }
    console.log(aa);  // still in the function scope so it output 11
    console.log(bb);  // should be 12
}
console.log(aa) // undefined nothing has change for the global aa
```

For more read this <kbd>[great Ebook](http://bonsaiden.github.io/JavaScript-Garden/#function.scopes)</kbd>

Comment: So do you mean `undefined` is the value that is being assigned to the variable in my case?

Comment: yes the value by default is `undefined` unless you assign manually a value, `var a = undefined` is equal to `var b;` `a === b`

Comment: Thank you for clearing my misconception. I always thought of `var a` as `nothing is there`. But now what I can understand is `there may occur a variable 'a' which is inside this scope but no value has been assigned to it`. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: `undefined` is a special value which means nothing has been defined. So not defining or defining undefined is kinda the same. About the scope here [a good ebook](http://bonsaiden.github.io/JavaScript-Garden/#function.scopes)

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `var aa;` from within your function.

What's happening here is [function scope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/bzt2dkta%28v=vs.94%29.aspx). You've declared `aa` as a local variable within `function a`. the local variable IS getting set to 11.